# Как задать диапазон Int в Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Как сделать так, чтобы в строке с типом INT могло содержаться значение только в диапазоне от 0 до 100?

Comment: Для версии 8.0.16 (и новее) просто напишите соотв. CHECK CONSTRAINT. Для версий младше - пишите проверяющий триггер (и учтите, что он не работает на каскадных операциях).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: @Akina также не забыть учесть, что поддержка триггеров начинается с версии 5.0.2

Comment: ...И требует привилегий SUPER для всей БД

Answer (score 1):

После объявления имени и типа столбца надо написать CHECK()  и в скобках указать условие или несколько условий.

Пример:
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
**'rating' int(11)** **CHECK(rating >= 0 AND rating <= 100)** NOT NULL)